# segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int test(char ch [10],int i,int j )
{
    if(i>=j) return 1;
    else if  (ch[i]!=ch[j]) return 0;
    else return (test(ch,i++,j--)); 
}

int main ()
{
    char  ch[10];
    int m,k;

    printf("Donner une chaine de caracteres :\n");
    scanf("%s",ch);
    k=strlen(ch);
    m=test(ch,0,k-1);
    if (m==1) printf ("expression palindrome \n");
    else printf ("expression non palindrome \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please state your question clearly. What have you done, what happens when...

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question, before giving us some code...

Comment: program exited with code 139 (segmentation fault) ,please help !

Comment: Are you overflowing your buffer? Also, test(ch,i++,j--) is undefined behaviour.

Comment: how should i change test(ch,i++,j--)

Comment: I compiled your program with gcc 4.5.2 and it has work fine

Comment: @Eugene well, it must be correct then.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing this:

`else return (test(ch,i++,j--));`

...with this:

`else return (test(ch,i+1,j-1));`

There's no need to assign back into 'i' and 'j' when making that call, since you don't reference them again in the same function invocation.  Moreover, `i++` evaluates to the original value of `i`, and not the value of `i + 1` (which is what you want here).

So your original code would never actually modify `i` and `j`, which would cause it to recurse infitely and cause a stack overflow (so I can't believe people were saying that this wasn't appropriate for SO).

Comment: This is one problem for sure. The other one is that OP could be overflowing the length 10 buffer.

Comment: wonderful ! thank you very much from Tunisia !

Comment: @maal: you could also use `++i` which will first increment `i`, then return its value.